# Haskell : Use -XFlexibleContexts to permit this?

Tags: haskell

My code as follows:

```
calcstep ::Integral a => a -> a
calcstep  n = calcstep2 n 0

calcstep2 :: Integral (Integral a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
calcstep2 1 k = k
calcstep2 n k | odd n = calcstep2 (n/2) (k+1)
              | otherwise = calcstep2 (n*3+1) (k+1)
```

The error is as follows:

> Non type-variable argument
>
> in the constraint: Integral (Integral a, Integral b)
>
> (Use -XFlexibleContexts to permit this)
>
> In the type signature for `calcstep2':
>         calcstep2 :: Integral (Integral a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
>
> Failed, modules loaded: none.

What does it mean? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The context `Integral (Integral a, Integral b)` is probably not what you intended. It is more likely that you want `(Integral a, Integral b)` as in

```
calcstep ::Integral a => a -> a
calcstep  n = calcstep2 n 0

calcstep2 :: (Integral a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
calcstep2 1 k = k
calcstep2 n k | odd n     = calcstep2 (n `div` 2) (k+1)
              | otherwise = calcstep2 (n * 3 + 1) (k+1)
```

Comment: Can you add more information about how to debug this type of errors (it can be not so obvious what is going on)?

Answer (score 19):

In `ghci` you can set `FlexibleContexts` like this:

```
:set -XFlexibleContexts
```

In the source file, at the beginning, you should use:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
```

In the GHC manual you can find more about [using language extensions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#pragmas).

In any case I think Chris' answer is closer to what you really want.

Comment: The link is broken. I suspect this is the updated one: https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/control.html