# usage of toSql (database.HDBC)

Tags: haskell

I do not understand how to use fromSql from database.HDBC.

```
*Main> toSql "foobar"
SqlString "foobar"
```

Until here, I feel confortable, I have something of type SqlString

Now, trying some round-trip :

```
*Main> fromSql $ toSql "foobar"

<interactive>:4:1: error:
    * Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible SqlValue a
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible SqlValue a => a
```

Ok, I put the FlexibleContexts on according to this thread [Haskell : Use -XFlexibleContexts to permit this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375556/haskell-use-xflexiblecontexts-to-permit-this)

```
*Main> :set -XFlexibleContexts
*Main> fromSql $ toSql "foobar"

<interactive>:8:1: error:
    * No instance for (Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible SqlValue ())
        arising from a use of `it'
    * In the first argument of `print', namely `it'
      In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Still KO, I understand here that whatever type the round trip create, this stuff is not a valid argument for the print.

I am checking the type :

```
*Main> res = fromSql $ toSql "foobar"
*Main> :t res
res :: Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible SqlValue a => a
```

And here I am lost... I would expect to have something like  [char] or String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a type annotation to get typechecking to succeed:

```
λ> fromSql $ toSql "foobar" :: String
"foobar"
```

If you're using this with more contextual code, you might be able to skip the annotation if it can be inferred, eg:

```
λ> putStrLn $ fromSql $ toSql "foobar"
foobar
```

As `putStrLn` has type `String -> IO ()`, the type is inferred automatically for you.

---

To try to give some intuition as to why this is needed:

The type of `toSql` is:

```
toSql :: Convertible a SqlValue => a -> SqlValue
```

Note that the result type (`SqlValue`) doesn't have any parameters about what type it contains - it's just a black box that could be a string, number etc. Given this, and looking at the type of `fromSql`:

```
fromSql :: Convertible SqlValue a => SqlValue -> a
```

...we can see that it takes this black box and has to return a value of a specific type from it. It can't restrict this type to be say `String` or `Int` as it has to be able to return different types depending on what's inside the black box, and the black box itself doesn't reveal any information about what's inside it at compile-time so it can't leverage that.

The only possible return type it can have, then, is some `a` (obeying the constraint `Convertible SqlValue a`), so you have to add the type constraint to force it to typecheck.

Comment: Thanks !  Indeed I think what confused me is the possibility of doing a round trip with a Maybe : fromJust $ Just "Foobar"   which works smoothly. 
But you pointed me that the data type is "SqlValue" not "SqlValue a".  Obviously this has the benefit of being able to put in a list heteregenous SqlValue types. ( [Just 5, Just "Foobar]  being impossible).