# readCol = map fromSql non type-variable argument

Tags: database, sqlite, haskell

```
:i fromSql 
fromSql ::
  convertible-1.1.1.0:Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible SqlValue a =>
  SqlValue -> a
        -- Defined in ‘Database.HDBC.SqlValue’
```

If I run e.g `map fromSql (EXAMPLESQL)` it outputs ok. But if I redefine it as `readCol = map fromSql` I get the error:

```
readCol = map fromSql

<interactive>:23:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: convertible-1.1.1.0:Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible
                             SqlValue b
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        readCol :: forall b.
                   convertible-1.1.1.0:Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible SqlValue b =>
                   [SqlValue] -> [b]
```

How to solve this?

Comment: As it recommended, enable FlexibleContexts. It is quite reliable and trusted extension. I think it would surely be integrated in upcoming haskell report.

Comment: Thank you. I've set the solution accordingly. Solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375556/haskell-use-xflexiblecontexts-to-permit-this

Answer (score 1):

I used the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375556/haskell-use-xflexiblecontexts-to-permit-this):

In ghci you can set FlexibleContexts like this:

```
:set -XFlexibleContexts
```

In the source file, at the beginning, you should use:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
```